# Django model cross reference issue

Tags: django-models

I'm having a problem with some models in django. I want to set up 2 Tables ( Table and Order ) like this:

### Code

```
class Table(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_order = models.OneToOneField(Order, blank=True)
    is_free = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Table " + str(self.number) + " - Restaurant " + str(self.restaurant)


class Order(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Dish, through='DishOrder')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Order " + self.id
```

### Error

When tryng to makemigrations django block me because 'Order is not definied'.
I understand the problem but I can't move the Order class before Table class otherwise the error will be 'Table not definied'

How can I solve this?